# Making tables visible based on what radio button is selected - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, radio-button

I currently have a first page with radio buttons. I want the second page to show a different table for every different radio button.

My view:

```
    <?php echo form_open('employee','class="form-inline"'); ?>
    <h3>Select User</h3>

        <?php echo form_dropdown('user-name', $name_list2);?>

    <h3>Select A Shift For Person 2</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="shift-type2" value="5" class="btn" data-toggle="button" <?php echo set_radio('shift-type2', '5'); ?> >Opening Cook</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="shift-type2" value="6" class="btn" data-toggle="button" <?php echo set_radio('shift-type2', '6'); ?> >Opening Order-Taker</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="shift-type2" value="7" class="btn" data-toggle="button" <?php echo set_radio('shift-type2', '7'); ?> >Closer</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="shift-type2" value="8" class="btn" data-toggle="button" <?php echo set_radio('shift-type2', '8'); ?> >Saturday Cook</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="shift-type2" value="9" class="btn" data-toggle="button" <?php echo set_radio('shift-type2', '9'); ?> >Saturday Order-Taker</input><br>



</form>

</div>
```

I am not sure what to put on my controller. I imagine it's something that will grab the values and use if statements to display each tables. So it should be something like: "If value equals 2, then display table B."

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `switch` and grap the post value then you compare it and show the required view

```
function switcherOnButton()
{
$value = $this->input->post('shift-type2'); 

switch($value)
{
   case '6':
      $this->load->view('view6'); 
   break; 
   case '7':
      $this->load->view('view7'); 
   break; 
   case '8':
      $this->load->view('view8'); 
   break; 
   case '9':
      $this->load->view('view9'); 
   break; 
}
}
```

I hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

At your model

```
 function get()
 {
     $value=$_POST['shift-type2']; //get posted data from radio button

     switch($value)
     {
      case '5':
       $table_name="table_name5"; 
      break; 

      case '6':
       $table_name="table_name6"; 
      break; 

     case '7':
      $table_name="table_name7"; 
     break;     
   }

    $query=$this->db->get($table_name);
   return $query->result_array();
  }
```